# Docker image with python & alpine failure due missing compiler error

Tags: python, docker, cron, alpine-linux

I'm looking for a docker image with both python3 and a crontab.
When I use `python:latest` as a base, I have no cron, but all required python packages install without problem.

When I use alpine as a base I have the (busybox) cron working, but are unable to install specific python package due to compiler error.

The same applies when I use `python:alpine`.

```
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko->-r required_python_packages.txt (line 6))
  Downloading PyNaCl-1.1.2.tar.gz (3.1MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options
        passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.
        See the error messages above.
```

Any advise?

Comment: shiw your various Dockerfiles, add to an alpine Dockerfile `apk add --update missing_library`

Answer (score 31):

You need a working compiler, the easiest way around this is to install the build-base package like so:

```
apk add --no-cache --virtual .pynacl_deps build-base python3-dev libffi-dev
```

This will install various tools that are required to compile pynacl and  `pip install pynacl` will now succeed.

Note it is optional to use the `--virtual` flag but it makes it easy to trim the image because you can run `apk del .pynacl_deps` later in your Dockerfile as they are not needed any more and would reduce the overall size of the image.

Comment: Thx. `docker build --build-arg http_proxy=<...> --build-arg http_proxy=<...> ...` (behind proxy):
```
(5/22) Installing libgomp (6.4.0-r5)
ERROR: libgomp-6.4.0-r5: BAD archive
(6/22) Installing libatomic (6.4.0-r5)
ERROR: libatomic-6.4.0-r5: BAD archive
(8/22) Installing libgcc (6.4.0-r5)
ERROR: libgcc-6.4.0-r5: BAD archive
(17/22) Installing fortify-headers (0.9-r0)
ERROR: Failed to create usr/include/fortify/wchar.h: I/O error
ERROR: fortify-headers-0.9-r0: IO ERROR
(22/22) Installing .pynacl_deps (0)
```
The other pkgs inst. fine, so strange. W/out proxy it instd these as well.

Comment: Note that in order to not increase image size, all three commands – "apk add", pip, and "apk del" must be in the same "RUN" command in the Dockerfile.