# Python docker build up error

Tags: python, docker-compose

[image]

I got this error when i run command

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Docker File:

```
 FROM alpine

ARG AWS_RDS_USER
ARG AWS_RDS_PASSWORD
ARG AWS_RDS_HOST
ARG AWS_RDS_DATABASE
ARG LOCALE_SERVICE_URL
ARG CRYPTO_KEY

ENV APP_DIR=/app
ENV APP_ENV=production
ENV DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING=mysql://${AWS_RDS_USER}:${AWS_RDS_PASSWORD}@${AWS_RDS_HOST}/${AWS_RDS_DATABASE}
ENV LOCALE_SERVICE_URL=$LOCALE_SERVICE_URL
ENV CRYPTO_KEY=$CRYPTO_KEY

COPY build/requirements.txt build/app.ini ${APP_DIR}/
COPY build/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY api ${APP_DIR}/api

RUN apk add --no-cache curl python pkgconfig python-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev musl-dev make gcc

RUN curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual .build-deps autoconf gcc make g++ python-dev && \
    apk add nginx uwsgi uwsgi-python py2-pip py-mysqldb && \
    chown -R nginx:nginx ${APP_DIR} && \
    chmod 777 /run/ -R && \
    chmod 777 /root/ -R && \
    pip2 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip2 install -r ${APP_DIR}/requirements.txt && \
    apk del .build-deps && \
    rm -fR tmp/* && \
    pw_migrate migrate --database=$DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING --directory=$APP_DIR/api/migrations -v

EXPOSE 80

CMD nginx && uwsgi --ini ${APP_DIR}/app.ini
```

For solution,  I tried to install below packages

1) gcc package.

2) libffi packages.

3) pip openssl packages.

But still error is not resolved. Any help should be appreciated

Comment: Please add your `Dockerfile` to the question.

Comment: you can start by simply launching `alpine` container and running the commands. This will help you get the right solution without endless builds

Comment: i am installing these for my pip instal to run ok `apk add --update --no-cache --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev libc-dev linux-headers`, also you are crazy if you let run `migrate` when you build the image, run it on start of the image

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028650/docker-image-with-python-alpine-failure-due-missing-compiler-error)

> This is because you need a working compiler, the easiest way around
>   this is too install the build-base package like so:
>
> `apk add --no-cache --virtual .pynacl_deps build-base python3-dev
>   libffi-dev` This will install various tools that are required to
>   compile pynacl and  pip install pynacl will now succeed.
>
> Note it is optional to use the `--virtual` flag but it makes it easy to
>   trim the image because you can run `apk del .pynacl_deps` later in your
>   dockerfile as they are not needed any more and would reduce the
>   overall size of the image.